# First derivative of curve and onset and endset points

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, data, physics

If I have the following data:

```
data={{7.96774, 1.56726}, {8.135, 1.5464}, {8.302, 1.50128}, {8.469, 
  1.48137}, {8.631, 1.70807}, {8.793, 1.95927}, {8.956, 
  2.12076}, {9.121, 2.18059}, {9.291, 2.01987}, {9.462, 
  1.80644}, {9.634, 1.57076}, {9.806, 1.33481}, {9.977, 
  1.12396}, {10.147, 0.928622}, {10.318, 0.751031}, {10.488, 
  0.589379}, {10.658, 0.437464}, {10.827, 0.311543}, {10.996, 
  0.197116}, {11.165, 0.0954133}, {11.333, 
  0.00229275}, {11.502, -0.0729584}, {11.67, -0.139729}, {11.838, \
-0.197912}, {12.005, -0.250487}, {12.173, -0.293136}, {12.34, \
-0.329747}, {12.508, -0.362385}, {12.675, -0.390908}, {12.842, \
-0.414867}, {13.009, -0.435075}, {13.176, -0.452986}, {13.343, \
-0.469488}, {13.51, -0.48198}, {13.677, -0.493373}, {13.844, \
-0.503265}, {14.011, -0.513132}, {14.178, -0.519815}, {14.345, \
-0.525868}, {14.511, -0.531485}, {14.678, -0.536355}, {14.845, \
-0.540827}, {15.012, -0.5453}, {15.179, -0.549184}, {15.345, \
-0.5528}, {15.512, -0.554133}, {15.679, -0.556115}, {15.845, \
-0.558311}, {16.012, -0.560484}, {16.179, -0.562462}, {16.346, \
-0.564472}, {16.512, -0.566367}, {16.679, -0.568136}, {16.846, \
-0.569721}, {17.012, -0.571179}, {17.179, -0.57258}, {17.346, \
-0.573914}, {17.513, -0.575043}, {17.679, -0.576335}, {17.846, \
-0.577633}, {18.013, -0.578875}, {18.179, -0.580188}, {18.346, \
-0.581351}, {18.513, -0.582421}, {18.68, -0.583426}, {18.846, \
-0.584218}, {19.013, -0.585184}, {19.18, -0.586136}, {19.346, \
-0.587095}, {19.513, -0.587872}, {19.68, -0.588636}, {19.846, \
-0.589461}, {20.013, -0.590312}, {20.18, -0.590885}, {20.346, \
-0.591489}, {20.513, -0.592108}, {20.68, -0.592725}, {20.847, \
-0.593118}, {21.013, -0.593568}, {21.18, -0.594134}, {21.347, \
-0.594723}, {21.513, -0.595303}, {21.68, -0.595876}, {21.847, \
-0.596392}, {22.013, -0.596852}, {22.18, -0.59754}, {22.347, \
-0.59816}, {22.513, -0.598651}, {22.68, -0.599116}, {22.847, \
-0.599463}, {23.014, -0.599827}, {23.18, -0.600176}, {23.347, \
-0.600484}, {23.514, -0.600702}, {23.68, -0.600953}, {23.847, \
-0.601148}, {24.014, -0.601342}, {24.18, -0.601613}, {24.347, \
-0.601853}, {24.514, -0.602033}, {24.68, -0.602217}, {24.847, \
-0.602353}, {25.014, -0.602501}, {25.18, -0.602686}, {25.347, \
-0.602844}, {25.514, -0.603073}, {25.681, -0.603369}, {25.847, \
-0.603674}, {26.014, -0.603931}, {26.181, -0.604298}, {26.347, \
-0.60456}, {26.514, -0.604722}, {26.681, -0.604833}, {26.847, \
-0.604767}, {27.014, -0.604874}, {27.181, -0.604976}, {27.347, \
-0.60502}, {27.514, -0.605058}, {27.681, -0.605066}, {27.847, \
-0.605084}, {28.014, -0.605096}, {28.181, -0.60503}, {28.347, \
-0.60502}, {28.514, -0.60502}, {28.681, -0.605039}, {28.847, \
-0.605074}, {29.014, -0.605204}, {29.181, -0.605306}, {29.348, \
-0.60545}, {29.514, -0.605637}, {29.681, -0.605699}, {29.848, \
-0.605807}, {30.014, -0.606053}, {30.181, -0.606138}, {30.348, \
-0.606147}, {30.514, -0.60618}, {30.681, -0.606272}, {30.848, \
-0.606108}, {31.014, -0.606031}, {31.181, -0.606013}, {31.348, \
-0.60598}, {31.514, -0.605902}, {31.681, -0.605936}, {31.848, \
-0.605997}, {32.014, -0.606072}, {32.181, -0.606327}, {32.348, \
-0.606351}, {32.514, -0.606276}, {32.681, -0.606226}, {32.848, \
-0.605964}, {33.015, -0.605738}, {33.181, -0.605506}, {33.348, \
-0.605236}, {33.515, -0.60476}, {33.681, -0.604431}, {33.848, \
-0.60414}, {34.015, -0.603862}, {34.181, -0.603599}, {34.348, \
-0.603327}, {34.515, -0.60305}, {34.681, -0.602719}, {34.848, \
-0.602565}, {35.015, -0.602495}, {35.181, -0.602398}, {35.348, \
-0.602309}, {35.515, -0.602281}, {35.681, -0.602162}, {35.848, \
-0.602023}, {36.015, -0.601898}, {36.181, -0.601475}, {36.348, \
-0.601105}, {36.515, -0.600692}, {36.681, -0.600351}, {36.848, \
-0.599836}, {37.015, -0.599475}, {37.181, -0.599255}, {37.348, \
-0.599028}, {37.515, -0.598888}, {37.681, -0.598731}, {37.848, \
-0.598552}, {38.015, -0.598311}, {38.181, -0.598059}, {38.348, \
-0.597773}, {38.515, -0.597423}, {38.681, -0.597049}, {38.848, \
-0.596591}, {39.015, -0.596251}, {39.181, -0.595913}, {39.348, \
-0.595509}, {39.515, -0.595196}, {39.681, -0.59492}, {39.848, \
-0.5947}, {40.015, -0.594539}, {40.181, -0.594312}, {40.348, \
-0.594081}, {40.515, -0.593753}, {40.681, -0.593377}, {40.848, \
-0.592924}, {41.015, -0.592517}, {41.181, -0.592192}, {41.348, \
-0.5919}, {41.515, -0.591724}, {41.682, -0.591522}, {41.848, \
-0.591297}, {42.015, -0.591051}, {42.182, -0.590863}, {42.348, \
-0.590617}, {42.515, -0.590331}, {42.682, -0.590027}, {42.848, \
-0.589566}, {43.015, -0.589177}, {43.182, -0.58879}, {43.348, \
-0.588402}, {43.515, -0.587871}, {43.682, -0.58738}, {43.848, \
-0.586918}, {44.015, -0.586488}, {44.182, -0.585995}, {44.348, \
-0.585604}, {44.515, -0.585279}, {44.682, -0.584964}, {44.848, \
-0.584649}, {45.015, -0.584284}, {45.182, -0.583918}, {45.348, \
-0.583518}, {45.515, -0.582852}, {45.682, -0.582295}, {45.848, \
-0.581756}, {46.015, -0.58121}, {46.182, -0.580592}, {46.348, \
-0.580079}, {46.515, -0.579607}, {46.682, -0.579119}, {46.848, \
-0.57872}, {47.015, -0.578336}, {47.182, -0.577935}, {47.348, \
-0.577503}, {47.515, -0.576997}, {47.682, -0.57654}, {47.848, \
-0.576063}, {48.015, -0.575598}, {48.182, -0.575137}, {48.348, \
-0.574748}, {48.515, -0.57433}, {48.682, -0.573862}, {48.848, \
-0.573473}, {49.015, -0.573086}, {49.182, -0.57269}, {49.348, \
-0.572278}, {49.515, -0.571792}, {49.682, -0.571332}, {49.848, \
-0.570937}, {50.015, -0.570629}, {50.182, -0.570324}, {50.348, \
-0.569964}, {50.515, -0.56952}, {50.682, -0.569036}, {50.848, \
-0.568532}, {51.015, -0.567985}, {51.182, -0.567396}, {51.348, \
-0.566792}, {51.515, -0.566179}, {51.682, -0.565589}, {51.848, \
-0.565}, {52.015, -0.564412}, {52.182, -0.563903}, {52.348, \
-0.563229}, {52.515, -0.562493}, {52.682, -0.561707}, {52.848, \
-0.560841}, {53.015, -0.560048}, {53.182, -0.559269}, {53.348, \
-0.558481}, {53.515, -0.557784}, {53.682, -0.557025}, {53.848, \
-0.556204}, {54.015, -0.555307}, {54.182, -0.554469}, {54.348, \
-0.553661}, {54.515, -0.552836}, {54.681, -0.551979}, {54.848, \
-0.551237}, {55.015, -0.550454}, {55.181, -0.549659}, {55.348, \
-0.548882}, {55.515, -0.548084}, {55.681, -0.547209}, {55.848, \
-0.5463}, {56.015, -0.54531}, {56.181, -0.544287}, {56.348, \
-0.543327}, {56.515, -0.542344}, {56.681, -0.541325}, {56.848, \
-0.540258}, {57.015, -0.539077}, {57.181, -0.537932}, {57.348, \
-0.536788}, {57.515, -0.535376}, {57.681, -0.533994}, {57.848, \
-0.532621}, {58.015, -0.531276}, {58.181, -0.529846}, {58.348, \
-0.5284}, {58.514, -0.526927}, {58.681, -0.525388}, {58.848, \
-0.523733}, {59.014, -0.522078}, {59.181, -0.520365}, {59.348, \
-0.518596}, {59.514, -0.516641}, {59.681, -0.51474}, {59.847, \
-0.512765}, {60.014, -0.510794}, {60.181, -0.508724}, {60.347, \
-0.50666}, {60.514, -0.504548}, {60.681, -0.502374}, {60.847, \
-0.500135}, {61.014, -0.497802}, {61.18, -0.495308}, {61.347, \
-0.492812}, {61.514, -0.489924}, {61.68, -0.487058}, {61.847, \
-0.484101}, {62.013, -0.481123}, {62.18, -0.477741}, {62.347, \
-0.474428}, {62.513, -0.471069}, {62.68, -0.467665}, {62.846, \
-0.463933}, {63.013, -0.460164}, {63.179, -0.456292}, {63.346, \
-0.452003}, {63.513, -0.44743}, {63.679, -0.442982}, {63.846, \
-0.438375}, {64.012, -0.433582}, {64.179, -0.428323}, {64.345, \
-0.423092}, {64.512, -0.417727}, {64.678, -0.41222}, {64.845, \
-0.406054}, {65.011, -0.399997}, {65.178, -0.393814}, {65.344, \
-0.387497}, {65.511, -0.380519}, {65.677, -0.373662}, {65.844, \
-0.366692}, {66.01, -0.359231}, {66.177, -0.351331}, {66.343, \
-0.343502}, {66.51, -0.335524}, {66.676, -0.32738}, {66.842, \
-0.318816}, {67.009, -0.310346}, {67.175, -0.301801}, {67.342, \
-0.293172}, {67.508, -0.284347}, {67.675, -0.275607}, {67.841, \
-0.266868}, {68.007, -0.258133}, {68.174, -0.24947}, {68.34, \
-0.240872}, {68.507, -0.232346}, {68.673, -0.223895}, {68.84, \
-0.215818}, {69.006, -0.207777}, {69.172, -0.199948}, {69.339, \
-0.192293}, {69.505, -0.185224}, {69.672, -0.177854}, {69.838, \
-0.171028}, {70.005, -0.16521}, {70.171, -0.160071}, {70.338, \
-0.154877}, {70.504, -0.150639}, {70.671, -0.1471}, {70.838, \
-0.144246}, {71.004, -0.141337}, {71.171, -0.139207}, {71.337, \
-0.137564}, {71.504, -0.137787}, {71.671, -0.137724}, {71.837, \
-0.13802}, {72.004, -0.138688}, {72.171, -0.140468}, {72.337, \
-0.14218}, {72.504, -0.14421}, {72.671, -0.146476}, {72.838, \
-0.14986}, {73.005, -0.153233}, {73.171, -0.156506}, {73.338, \
-0.15985}, {73.505, -0.163613}, {73.672, -0.167102}, {73.838, \
-0.170444}, {74.005, -0.173696}, {74.172, -0.176653}, {74.339, \
-0.179492}, {74.505, -0.182101}, {74.672, -0.184524}, {74.839, \
-0.186456}, {75.006, -0.188589}, {75.172, -0.190549}, {75.339, \
-0.192324}, {75.506, -0.193653}, {75.672, -0.194985}, {75.839, \
-0.196205}, {76.006, -0.197348}, {76.173, -0.197963}, {76.339, \
-0.198745}, {76.506, -0.199434}, {76.673, -0.200046}, {76.839, \
-0.200399}, {77.006, -0.200728}, {77.173, -0.200978}, {77.339, \
-0.201176}, {77.506, -0.20113}, {77.673, -0.201187}, {77.839, \
-0.201292}, {78.006, -0.201484}, {78.173, -0.201872}, {78.339, \
-0.202183}, {78.506, -0.202464}, {78.673, -0.202759}, {78.839, \
-0.203127}, {79.006, -0.203282}, {79.173, -0.203404}, {79.339, \
-0.203574}, {79.506, -0.203292}, {79.673, -0.203095}, {79.839, \
-0.20295}, {80.006, -0.202848}, {80.173, -0.202596}, {80.339, \
-0.202421}, {80.506, -0.202254}, {80.673, -0.202119}, {80.839, \
-0.202066}, {81.006, -0.20202}, {81.173, -0.201953}, {81.339, \
-0.201876}, {81.506, -0.201804}, {81.673, -0.201761}, {81.84, \
-0.201765}, {82.006, -0.201758}, {82.173, -0.201739}, {82.34, \
-0.201773}, {82.506, -0.201785}, {82.673, -0.201728}, {82.84, \
-0.201631}, {83.006, -0.201539}, {83.173, -0.201393}, {83.34, \
-0.201213}, {83.506, -0.200869}, {83.673, -0.200648}, {83.84, \
-0.200468}, {84.006, -0.200313}, {84.173, -0.200043}, {84.34, \
-0.199789}, {84.506, -0.199548}, {84.673, -0.199318}, {84.84, \
-0.199003}, {85.006, -0.198857}, {85.173, -0.198756}, {85.34, \
-0.198618}, {85.506, -0.198503}, {85.673, -0.198315}, {85.84, \
-0.198102}, {86.006, -0.197854}, {86.173, -0.197428}, {86.339, \
-0.197051}, {86.506, -0.196711}, {86.673, -0.196389}, {86.839, \
-0.19602}, {87.006, -0.195708}, {87.173, -0.195422}, {87.339, \
-0.195171}, {87.506, -0.194906}, {87.673, -0.194636}, {87.839, \
-0.19441}, {88.006, -0.194146}, {88.173, -0.193767}, {88.339, \
-0.193419}, {88.506, -0.19307}, {88.673, -0.192756}, {88.839, \
-0.192465}, {89.006, -0.192252}, {89.173, -0.192063}, {89.339, \
-0.191836}, {89.506, -0.191648}, {89.673, -0.191416}, {89.839, \
-0.191232}, {90.006, -0.19105}, {90.173, -0.190693}, {90.339, \
-0.190372}, {90.506, -0.190043}, {90.673, -0.189726}, {90.839, \
-0.189441}, {91.006, -0.189198}, {91.173, -0.189069}, {91.339, \
-0.189035}, {91.506, -0.189091}, {91.673, -0.18905}, {91.839, \
-0.189031}, {92.006, -0.189143}, {92.173, -0.18921}, {92.339, \
-0.18926}, {92.506, -0.189836}, {92.673, -0.191524}, {92.84, \
-0.194287}, {93.006, -0.193717}, {93.173, -0.19187}, {93.339, \
-0.189806}, {93.506, -0.187984}, {93.673, -0.18646}, {93.839, \
-0.185048}, {94.006, -0.183745}, {94.173, -0.183}, {94.339, \
-0.18212}, {94.506, -0.181331}, {94.673, -0.180589}, {94.839, \
-0.180059}, {95.006, -0.17945}, {95.172, -0.178897}, {95.339, \
-0.178433}, {95.506, -0.1781}, {95.672, -0.177813}, {95.839, \
-0.177548}, {96.006, -0.177288}, {96.172, -0.177164}, {96.339, \
-0.176959}, {96.506, -0.176694}, {96.672, -0.176434}, {96.839, \
-0.176044}, {97.006, -0.175679}, {97.172, -0.175322}, {97.339, \
-0.175014}, {97.506, -0.174796}, {97.672, -0.174649}, {97.839, \
-0.174519}, {98.006, -0.174338}, {98.172, -0.174389}, {98.339, \
-0.174305}, {98.506, -0.174113}, {98.672, -0.173865}, {98.839, \
-0.173536}, {99.006, -0.173253}, {99.172, -0.172948}, {99.339, \
-0.172632}, {99.506, -0.172378}, {99.672, -0.172128}, {99.839, \
-0.17183}, {100.006, -0.171526}, {100.172, -0.171247}, {100.339, \
-0.170966}, {100.506, -0.170713}, {100.672, -0.1705}, {100.839, \
-0.170334}, {101.006, -0.170237}, {101.172, -0.1701}, {101.339, \
-0.169865}, {101.506, -0.169764}, {101.672, -0.16957}, {101.839, \
-0.169297}, {102.006, -0.168997}, {102.172, -0.168589}, {102.339, \
-0.168215}, {102.506, -0.167789}, {102.672, -0.167288}, {102.839, \
-0.171012}, {103.006, -0.172892}, {103.172, -0.172753}, {103.339, \
-0.171707}, {103.506, -0.1707}, {103.672, -0.170053}, {103.839, \
-0.169348}, {104.006, -0.168645}, {104.172, -0.168057}, {104.339, \
-0.167494}, {104.506, -0.166991}, {104.672, -0.16653}, {104.839, \
-0.166237}, {105.006, -0.16586}, {105.172, -0.165496}, {105.339, \
-0.165154}, {105.506, -0.164937}, {105.672, -0.164806}, {105.839, \
-0.164675}, {106.006, -0.164509}, {106.172, -0.164371}, {106.339, \
-0.164071}, {106.506, -0.163779}, {106.672, -0.163508}, {106.839, \
-0.162947}, {107.006, -0.162416}, {107.172, -0.162379}, {107.339, \
-0.162437}, {107.505, -0.161247}, {107.671, -0.140996}, {107.836, \
-0.0900667}}
```

Which plotted like this: `ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{30, 90}, {-0.7, 0}}]` gives:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can I get the first derivative curve of that data?
2. How can I get the onset of the peak and the endset of the peak based on the first derivative of the data?. Here's a picture of a paper where they take the onset and endset of several curves based on the first derivative. **Since I realized that onset is a little bit trickier, it would be enough just to find the endset point (see the two images below)**

[image]

For the case of this exercise, using the suggestion of MarcoB (`int = Interpolation[data]; Plot[int'[x], {x, 30, 90}, PlotRange -> All]`), I get:

[image]

where the endset point is shown in the image and can be defined as "the value of the x-axis where you get the lowest point in the y-axis at the end of the peak".

**EDIT OF WHAT I AM USING TO TRY TO FIND THE ENDSET POINT:**

I am using the following to find the endset point: `FindMinimum[{int'[x], 40 <= x <= 80}, {x, 40}]`. However, it gives me `{0.00229078, {x -> 46.9328}}` in which obviously the x value of `46.9328` is wrong. Visually inspection shows that the endset point is around `73`. How can I fix this?

Comment: For the first question you might want to look at `InterpolatingFunction`

Comment: What is your definition for onset and endset?

Comment: For the first part, `int = Interpolation[data]; Plot[int'[x], {x, 30, 90}, PlotRange -> All]`. For the second part, it depends on how you define those points.

Comment: @BobHanlon I added a figure to show the onset and endset points of several similar plots. I think finding only the endpoint should be fine for my case. Thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon I think the endset point can be defined as "the value of the x-axis where you get the lowest point in the y-axis at the end of the peak" (see the extra image I added)